# Can I instruct predict to ignore error rows in R?

Tags: r, machine-learning, predict

I have a training data set that I am sampling from (randomly) to train a model in R.

```
sampleSize <- floor(0.1 * nrow(trainingDataFrame))
train_index <- sample(seq_len(nrow(trainingDataFrame)), size = sampleSize)
trainDF <- trainingDataFrame[train_index,]
fit <- train(dependentVariable ~ ., data=trainDF,
             trControl = trainControl(method = "cv",number = 10),method="lm")
```

I am then using that model to `predict` values across a separate testing data set. However, there is a factor field that, for some of the rows in my testing dataset, occasionally has values that were not encountered in the training set because of the fact that I'm sampling randomly for the training set. This results in a `"factor ... has new levels"` error.

I am actually repeating this *sample-train-predict* process over a number of iterations, so each testing dataset record will very likely have some valid predictions in the end. Thus, for my use case, it is actually OK for certain records to be un-`predict`-able in any particular iteration. I would like to not have to exclude the field in question from the model training.

Instead, **is it possible to instruct the `predict` function to give me `na` or some other default value for these invalid rows?**

Comment: You could use `predict` with `tryCatch`, or `purrr::safely()`? Or you could get the levels present in the training set for each iteration, and filter the test dataset before using `predict`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possibility.

The key is define your own `predict` function that compares levels of `factor` variables from the `lm` object with those from `newdata`. We then `predict` only on those observations with matching `factor` levels, and return `NA` for all others.

I'll demonstrate using the `mtcars` data.

1. Let's first create sample data consisting of one numeric response (`mpg`) and 3 categorical predictor variables (`cyl`, `gear`, `carb`).

   ```
   library(tidyverse)
   df <- mtcars %>%
       select(mpg, cyl, gear, carb) %>%
       mutate_at(vars(-mpg), as.factor)
   ```
2. We then train the model on a training datasets of observations that have only some (but not all) factor levels for `cyl` and `gear`.

   ```
   df.train <- df %>% filter(cyl %in% c(4, 6) & gear %in% c(3, 4))
   ```
3. We fit a simple linear model.

   ```
   fit <- lm(mpg ~ ., data = df.train)
   ```
4. We now define a custom function that splits `newdata` into observations with (1) matching `factor` levels for which we can `predict` a response, and (2) "novel" levels for which we return `NA` as response.

   `factor` levels for all categorical variables are stored in `fit$xlevels` as a `list`. We use `purrr::imap` and `purrr::reduce(..., intersect)` to determine the row indices of those observations from `newdata` that have matching `factor` levels.

   ```
   my.predict <- function(fit, newdata) {
       lvls <- fit$xlevels
       idx <- reduce(imap(lvls, ~which(newdata[, .y] %in% .x)), intersect)
       res <- rep(NA, nrow(newdata))
       res[idx] <- predict(fit, newdata = newdata[idx, ])
       return(res)
   }
   ```
5. We confirm results on the full `df` dataset:

   ```
   df$pred <- my.predict(fit, df)
   df
   #    mpg cyl gear carb  pred
   #1  21.0   6    4    4 19.75
   #2  21.0   6    4    4 19.75
   #3  22.8   4    4    1 29.10
   #4  21.4   6    3    1 19.75
   #5  18.7   8    3    2    NA
   #6  18.1   6    3    1 19.75
   #7  14.3   8    3    4    NA
   #8  24.4   4    4    2 24.75
   #9  22.8   4    4    2 24.75
   #10 19.2   6    4    4 19.75
   #11 17.8   6    4    4 19.75
   #12 16.4   8    3    3    NA
   #13 17.3   8    3    3    NA
   #14 15.2   8    3    3    NA
   #15 10.4   8    3    4    NA
   #16 10.4   8    3    4    NA
   #17 14.7   8    3    4    NA
   #18 32.4   4    4    1 29.10
   #19 30.4   4    4    2 24.75
   #20 33.9   4    4    1 29.10
   #21 21.5   4    3    1 21.50
   #22 15.5   8    3    2    NA
   #23 15.2   8    3    2    NA
   #24 13.3   8    3    4    NA
   #25 19.2   8    3    2    NA
   #26 27.3   4    4    1 29.10
   #27 26.0   4    5    2    NA
   #28 30.4   4    5    2    NA
   #29 15.8   8    5    4    NA
   #30 19.7   6    5    6    NA
   #31 15.0   8    5    8    NA
   #32 21.4   4    4    2 24.75
   ```

Comment: Promising! I will try this tomorrow